# Running Redis on Windows as service

Tags: windows, service, redis

I have followed all the suggestions I can find.
I am running the current version on redis on windows 2008
I can run fin from command line
I can install the service but it doesnt run

I do...
redis-server --service-install redis.windows.conf
and get "redis successfully installed as a service"

Then I try to start the service doing...
redis-server --service-start redis.windows.conf --loglevel verbose
and get Redis service failed to start

I have made sure I have the .net framework 4.5.2 installed, I have tried with the firewall off and have played with security on the folder.

Anyone have any ideas?

(Merry Christmas all)

Answer (score 15):

Start redis server from the command line instead of as a service and it will display a more useful error message. If you are just using the default configuration it is most likely a problem with the maxmemory/maxheap configuration.

```
C:\redis>redis-server.exe redis.windows.conf
[1576] 04 Feb 10:32:54.172 #
The Windows version of Redis allocates a memory mapped heap for sharing with
the forked process used for persistence operations. In order to share this
memory, Windows allocates from the system paging file a portion equal to the
size of the Redis heap. At this time there is insufficient contiguous free
space available in the system paging file for this operation (Windows error
0x5AF). To work around this you may either increase the size of the system
paging file, or decrease the size of the Redis heap with the --maxheap flag.
Sometimes a reboot will defragment the system paging file sufficiently for
this operation to complete successfully.

Please see the documentation included with the binary distributions for more
details on the --maxheap flag.

Redis can not continue. Exiting.
```

Comment: In my case the Windows service wouldn't start and I tried this which told me the maxheap size was larger than the amount of free space I had on my drive and to lower the value or move the heap to a drive with more space.

Comment: and how did you do that i my case i have change my maxheap as well as maxmemory size to 256 MB but stil facing this error ?? please relpy must

Answer (score 9):

In my case the default commandline config did not have logging enabled and the service one did. And no place where it complains about that.
Try creating the directory ./Logs.

Comment: Yep, that was it!

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I came across it while trying to get a Win7x64 install working using binaries Redis-x64-2.8.2101. Couldn't get it to start despite fiddling with various options, no meaningful error given when run with the config, and only an apparently spurious disk space error when run natively.

There appears to be a issue on the github related, linked here for future benefit: https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/issues/267

Comment: I think I hit the same thing.  I set both maxheap and maxmemory to 1024 and it still gave me the error mentioned in Neil's answer. :(

Comment: @Daniel got any solution yet ?? well i just did the same thing but still getting the same error ??

Comment: @SudhanshuGaur it looks like the issue Daniel referenced was fixed in version 2.8.2103 so you shouldn't have that problem if you are on the latest version. 
In the issue above there is a reference to https://github.com/MSOpenTech/redis/issues/335 which might be what you are running into. If you haven't already done so try starting the service from an administrator command prompt and see if that works.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply by the way i have soved my problem my allocating max heap size this was the command redis-server redis.windows.conf --maxheap 1gb

Comment: Glad you found your solution :)